# Shell script to remove unity launcher(if present in Ubuntu 14.04 ) and/or the xfce panel (in the case of xubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, launcher

Just want shell script to remove unity launcher(if present in Ubuntu 14.04 ) and/or the xfce panel (in the case of xubuntu).

If anybody has idea about the same then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Command would mostly be `apt-get remove <package-name>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Firstly I want that when my program runs then Unity launcher should hide else it should show. If we can't do so then only the last option, remove unity launcher from my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Actually when my program runs then it should run on full screen mode. If anyone have any doubt/query then please let me know.

Comment: I have tried the below ways. Command to hide the launcher : gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 1

Command to show the launcher : gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-hide-mode 0 then go to System Setting -> Appearance -> Behavior -> Set Auto-hide Launcher to ON and set Reveal sensitivity to low and it works but I want to set  Reveal sensitivity to low by shell script.

Comment: It resolved here http://askubuntu.com/questions/643028/shell-script-to-remove-unity-launcherif-present-in-ubuntu-14-04-and-or-the-xf